# how to force webpack to load umd bundle of a library

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-upgrade

I'm writing an angular1 + angular2 hybrid application which uses webpack as package bundler.

In my code I import a library (@angular/upgrade) in this way

```
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
```

Angular upgrade library is sitting in node_module folder with the following tree structure (simplified):

```
@angular/upgrade
├── bundles
│   ├── upgrade-static.umd.js
│   ├── upgrade-static.umd.min.js
│   ├── upgrade.umd.js
│   └── upgrade.umd.min.js
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js
├── index.js.map
├── index.metadata.json
├── package.json
├── static
│   └── package.json
├── static.d.ts
├── static.js.map
├── static.metadata.json
└── static.js
```

The problem is that by default webpack resolve my import statement loading @angular/upgrade/static.js, an ES6 file which, once bundled with the rest of the code generate errors.

What I'd like webpack to do instead is loading @angular/upgrade/static/package.json which contains the right main definition pointing to the umd bundle

```
{"main": "../bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js"}
```

Is that achievable?

Thanks,
Gab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the module resolution described here:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html
should be able to do what I've described above by default, in order to achieve that I had to use the `resolve.alias` property. Here's the configuration that I've used:

```
resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.js', '.ts', '' ],
        modulesDirectories: [ path.resolve( __dirname, 'node_modules' ) ],
        alias: {
            '@angular/upgrade/static$': '../../node_modules/@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js'
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `import UpgradeModule from '@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js';` work?

Webpack only follows the `main` in package.json if package.json is at the root level of the npm module, so in this case you'll have to access the file you want directly.

Comment: Hi Drew. thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to be working. I get ``Cannot find name 'UpgradeModule'`` error during build time